# Power BI Service: DirectQuery + SQL Data Connection Issue in Report Visual

Tags: powerbi

I am working on a Live Dashboard using DirectQuery in PowerBI.
i am using datasource from SQL Server which updates every 15 minutes.

The dashboard is working fine on my PowerBi Desktop, but on PowerBI service, the Report is not being able to connect with the data source.
I have used On-Premise gateway and the data source is connected successfully and being refreshed every 15 minutes but the visual is not able to load the data.

I have attached photos of the error and the data source settings that I have on Desktop and on Gateway. Can some one please help to find out the connection issue occurring ?

Comment: I don't see any photos but regardless, please post the error message, not a photo

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: below is the error